# Multiply arrays to make matrix gives unexpected result

Tags: python

Suppose I have this code:

```
dim = 3
eye =  [[0] * dim] * dim
```

and it is a list of list, I checked

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Now, if I do this, I get:

```
eye[1][2] = 1
eye
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]
```

However, if I manually put in this expression, the above code works as expected:

```
eye2=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
eye2[1][2] = 1
eye2
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
```

What is the difference between the two ?

**Update:** Thanks for all the explanations, suppose I have this code:

```
a = [0]
type(a)
b = a * 3  # or b = [[0] *3]
```

So, b holds the 3 references to a. And I expect changing b[0] or b[1] or b[2] will change all 3 elements.
But this code shows the normal behavior, why is that ?

```
b[1] = 3
b
[0, 3, 0]
```

Comment: Someone taught me that I can do that kind of scalar multiplication to lists. If it turns out so weird, what is the application of this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any array entry is as a label of memory address and when you multiple it with a variable actually you create a pointer to `3` palace in your array ! you can figure it out with a list comprehension as below :

```
Matrix = [[0 for x in xrange(3)] for x in xrange(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim = 3
eye =  [[0] * dim] * dim
```

its make the copy of same, of if you change at one place it will be reflected to all

Answer (score 0):

```
dim = 3
eye =  [[0] * dim] * dim
print id(eye[0])
print id(eye[1])
print id(eye[2])
```

Ouput:-

```
139834251065392
139834251065392
139834251065392
```

So when you are doing `eye =  [[0] * dim] * dim` it actually refrencing
refrencing three `list` to same object that is `eye`.

while in other case

```
eye2=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
print id(eye2[1])
print id(eye2[2])
print id(eye2[0])
```

ouput:-

```
139863345170480
139863260058256
139863260067240
```

Here everytime refrence id is diffrent.

Comment: Very persuasive, thanks

Comment: @user1502776 Go through https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types. this will illustrate it.